# Start blank screensaver, disable mouse to wake

Tags: mouse, windows-10, screensaver

I'm looking for a way to turn off my monitor screen and disable mouse input from switching it back on (while staying logged in)

I need to use the screensaver function as the default built in screen-off timers won't work due to applications like skype running in the background forcing the monitor to stay awake/wake up.

So far I tried creating a shortcut to C:\Windows\System32\scrnsave.scr and set it to maximize, but moving the mouse still kicks me out.

I tried to disable my mouse by unticking "Allow this device to wake the computer" but it doesn't work as I guess a screensaver doesn't technically put the computer to sleep.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you are trying to achieve? I am not sure if you are looking for a sleep mode, that will trigger a screen saver which the mouse can't kill, or simply a screen saver that the mouse can't kill. Thank you

Comment: Either is fine, the point I was trying to make was that I need a mode that turns off the screen which both the mouse AND background applications won't force awake